# Как избежать выход за пределы экрана элемента в теле NestedScrollView?

Tags: java, android, nested-scrollview

Всем здравствуйте! Хотел добавить все элементы в `NestedScrollView` чтобы при небольшом дисплее можно было прокрутить. При добавлении их туда, часть расположено в верхней части экрана и они наложены друг на друга, а часть вышли за пределы экрана. Всё испробовал - не помогает. Что мне делать? Подскажите, пожалуйста!

**С NestedScrollView выглядит так:**

[image: Со ScrollView]

**Без NestedScrollView:**
[image: Без ScrollView]

**Код разметки xml с NestedScrollView:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_record2"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.testprogram.alex.tram.RecordActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ViewSwitcher
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/SerialNumberAnimation"
            android:layout_above="@+id/RouteNumberAnimation"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/SerialNumberEdit"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="@string/enter_sn"
                android:layout_marginBottom="23dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/SerialNumber" />

        </ViewSwitcher>

        <ViewSwitcher
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/RouteNumberAnimation"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/RouteNumberEdit"
                android:hint="@string/enter_route"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="28dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/RouteNumber" />
        </ViewSwitcher>

        <ViewSwitcher
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/PlusAnimation"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/PlusIn"
                android:contentDescription="@string/plus_in_description"
                android:src="@drawable/plus1" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/PlusOut"
                android:contentDescription="@string/plus_out_description"
                android:src="@drawable/plus2" />
        </ViewSwitcher>

        <ViewSwitcher
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/MinusAnimation"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/SerialNumberAnimation">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/MinusIn"
                android:contentDescription="@string/minus_in_description"
                android:src="@drawable/minus1" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/MinusOut"
                android:contentDescription="@string/minus_out_description"
                android:src="@drawable/minus2" />
        </ViewSwitcher>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fill_button_text"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/start_value_count"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/MinusAnimation"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/MinusAnimation"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/end_button_text"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Начало"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FAIL"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#ff0000" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PASS"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/SerialNumberAnimation"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/SerialNumberAnimation"
            android:textColor="#001aff" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**Код разметки xml без NestedScrollView:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.testprogram.alex.tram.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_record"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ViewSwitcher
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/SerialNumberAnimation"
        android:layout_above="@+id/RouteNumberAnimation"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/SerialNumberEdit"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="@string/enter_sn"
            android:layout_marginBottom="23dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/SerialNumber" />

    </ViewSwitcher>

    <ViewSwitcher
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/RouteNumberAnimation"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/RouteNumberEdit"
            android:hint="@string/enter_route"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/RouteNumber" />
    </ViewSwitcher>

    <ViewSwitcher
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/PlusAnimation"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/PlusIn"
            android:contentDescription="@string/plus_in_description"
            android:src="@drawable/plus1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/PlusOut"
            android:contentDescription="@string/plus_out_description"
            android:src="@drawable/plus2" />
    </ViewSwitcher>

    <ViewSwitcher
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/MinusAnimation"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/SerialNumberAnimation">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/MinusIn"
            android:contentDescription="@string/minus_in_description"
            android:src="@drawable/minus1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/MinusOut"
            android:contentDescription="@string/minus_out_description"
            android:src="@drawable/minus2" />
    </ViewSwitcher>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fill_button_text"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/MinusAnimation"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/MinusAnimation" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/start_value_count"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/MinusAnimation"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/MinusAnimation"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBarAnimation" />

    <ViewSwitcher
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarAnimation"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:theme="@style/BlueProgress" />

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            android:theme="@style/RedProgress" />
    </ViewSwitcher>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/end_button_text"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RouteNumberAnimation"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/PlusAnimation"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/PlusAnimation" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Начало"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FAIL"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PASS"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/SerialNumberAnimation"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/SerialNumberAnimation"
        android:textColor="#001aff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам нужен `RelativeLayout` и его нельзя заменить на, например, `LinearLayout`? и попробуйте ему проставить высоту в `wrap_contetn`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Изменил на `LinearLayout` и программа пишет такое предупреждение: **Invalid layout param in a _LinearLayout_** на следующие параметры: `alignParentBottom`, `alignRight`, `alignEnd`, `alignBottom`, `centerHorizontal`, `alignTop`, `below`, `alignParentLeft`, `alignParentStart`, `alignLeft`, `alignStart`. Можно ли их заменить на другие параметры, чтобы выровнять элементы?

Comment: Эти атрибуты работают только для RelativeLayout. При переходе на LunearLayout вам надо без них, заново скомпонавать свою разметку. Вы можете использовать оборачивание элементов в контейнеры, задавать размеры через "вес"

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Вообще ничего и никак не получается. Всё шло хорошо до того момента, пока я не начал компоновать viewswitchers (тот самый плюс и минус рядом с "**0**"). Никак компоноваться он не хочет как на моём скриншоте. Пытался добавить **горизонтальный** LinearLayout, в итоге получил ошибку: **ScrollView can host only one direct child**. Как мне их разместить правильно как на скриншоте? Может как то их сгруппировать?

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что только один ребёнок у ScrollView может быть. А разметка у вас слишком большая чтоб в ней сходу разобраться.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Большое спасибо Вам за очередную помощь! Добавил `RelativeLayout` в `LinearLayout`, сгруппировал `viewswitchers` и `textview` в этот `RelativeLayout` и установил им нужное выравнивание. `ScrollView` работает отлично. Тема закрыта.

Comment: Было бы не плохо, если бы вы описали процесс решения в ответе - может это её кому-то пригодится.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Уже написал ответ. Удачи! До свидания!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данная проблема решилась добавлением содержимого `RelativeLayout` в `LinearLayout`. А в `ScrollView` добавил этот `LinearLayout`. Там где не получалось выравнить, там использовался `RelativeLayout` и выравнивался элемент.

**Вот новый код xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_record2"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.testprogram.alex.tram.RecordActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.testprogram.alex.tram.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_record"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

            <ViewSwitcher
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/MinusAnimation"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/MinusIn"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/minus_in_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/minus1" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/MinusOut"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/minus_out_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/minus2" />
            </ViewSwitcher>

            <ViewSwitcher
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/PlusAnimation"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/PlusIn"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/plus_in_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/plus1" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/PlusOut"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/plus_out_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/plus2" />
            </ViewSwitcher>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="@string/start_value_count"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Начало"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FAIL"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PASS"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:textColor="#001aff"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

        <ViewSwitcher
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/SerialNumberAnimation">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/SerialNumberEdit"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="@string/enter_sn"
                android:layout_marginBottom="23dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/SerialNumber" />

        </ViewSwitcher>

        <ViewSwitcher
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/RouteNumberAnimation">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/RouteNumberEdit"
                android:hint="@string/enter_route"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="28dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/RouteNumber" />
        </ViewSwitcher>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fill_button_text"
            android:id="@+id/button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/end_button_text"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**Скриншот:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо большое пользователю **@ЮрийСПб** за помощь!